# postfix and local delivery

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

I have postfix on my Ubuntu 12. My server has real domain name (ddd).
But I would like to use postfix for web scripts on my server to sending out emails.

My real domain name is connected with GMail. And it works well.

I have username on my server like xxx. And the same username I have on GMail (which is connected with my domain name ddd).

So when scripts from my server sending out email to user xxx@ddd it's sending it to local user xxx on my server ddd. But i would like to receive it on GMail.

is it possible ?

my MX record is Ok.

```
ddd.        3600    IN  MX  5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
ddd.        3600    IN  MX  10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
ddd.        3600    IN  MX  10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
ddd.        3600    IN  MX  10 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
ddd.        3600    IN  MX  10 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
ddd.        3600    IN  MX  1 aspmx.l.google.com.
ddd.        3600    IN  MX  5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

my main dns record is also good. my real domain name is resolved well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use postfix; you have no need of its power and versatility.

Use a decent nullmailer such as [**ssmtp**](http://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP) instead.

Comment: would it be enough to install just mailutils ?

Comment: That depends; a MUA such as mutt or (al)pine can send over SMTP, but mail(1) cannot. If you're going to use this for applications sending mail, just use a nullmailer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is invalid. You created MX records for your domain that points to Gmail servers. You should receive the emails locally and then forward them to your Gmail account.

You can setup [virtual alias maps](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/) in postfix to do so.

Comment: can I have installed just mailutils and not any big MTA ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure `myhostname` is set to a hostname within your domain, not your domain itself.  Then, edit /etc/mailname (only works for Debian & Ubuntu) to have your domain, so `myorigin` will be set to this automatically.  Finally, edit `mydestination` sot it doesn't contain `$myorigin`.

This will stop mail for your domain that should be going to Gmail from being delivered locally.