# CentOS email setup for Wordpress

Tags: centos, email, postfix, sendmail, wordpress

I am moving an old Wordpress install to a new CentOS LEMP stack VPS. I want to set up email for the new VPS. It came with sendmail installed by default but I find it to be overkill. I just need a lightweight email setup for outbound mail from Wordpress contact forms, notifications, etc.

I currently use Google Apps for email on this domain. Is it possible to configure the VPS to relay emails through the same mailbox hosted on GApps? My old shared hosting account (WPEngine) had the notifications email set up with the same name as my GApps, however it wasn't authenticated through GApps. It was just coincidental that the email address ended up being the same.

My current setup with sendmail can send emails but they are not authenticated through GApps and the email address format looks like this: root@server.domain.com. I am aware I can masquerade the subdomain (localhost), but I am unsure how to change the user (root) to something else?

Ultimately, I do not want emails building up on the VPS, but rather in the GApps mailbox. I want to keep the VPS as clean as possible and relay all emails through GApps.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to use postfix or sendmail now? Wordpress has no support for SMTP itself, so you need either one.

Comment: I am open for suggestions.

Comment: [Don't use postfix; you have no need of its power and versatility](http://serverfault.com/a/380639/218590). Use a decent nullmailer such as [ssmtp](http://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP) instead.

Comment: I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Google Apps is not for transactional mail, but I could be wrong.

What may work better is a smart relay that makes use of an API, as this is typically lighter on resources than using a local MTA. Mandrill by Mailchimp is popular, but there is also Amazon SES, Rackspace Mailgun, and others. You can find WordPress plugins for these and they often have features for configuring outbound mail names and such.

I recommend spending the time to configure SPF and DKIM records, as transactional mail tends to end up in spam folders.